# How to add Date if today is last day of the month.?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, cocoa, nsdate

I am stuck a problem where i need to create a stepper by 7 day. I code for that but in case of last days of month it will remain continue with same month rather than it should be change in next month as well.
Same case needs to be implemented for the year.

For e.g if today is 30 dec 2016 then by adding 7 day it needs to be change as 7 jan 2017. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show some code.

Comment: Please check answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Here I have added 7 days from a particular date.

```
    // Enter current date
    NSString *currentDate = @"2016-12-30";

    // Set number of days to add
    int addDaysCount = 7;

    // Set date formatter
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    // Convert string to NSDate
    NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:currentDate];

    // Initialize date component
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setDay:addDaysCount];

    // Retrieve date with increased days count
    NSDate *newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]
                       dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                       toDate:dateFromString options:0];

    NSLog(@"Current date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
    NSLog(@"Updated date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]);
```

Comment: This can be made simpler by using the `NSCalendar` method `dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options:`.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *sevenDaysAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:+7*24*60*60];
```

Here add 7 days add to your current date

Comment: I Already follow the same code but by adding the day it will not change the month as well..+(NSDate*)getDateByAdding:(int)dayes daysInTheDate :(NSDate *)givenDate{
    return [givenDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*dayes];
}

Comment: used my ans in your function and check.

NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // here used your date
NSDate *sevenDaysAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:+7*24*60*60];

Comment: @ Anupam Gupta I have compiled your method and getting the out put correctly by adding 9 days with today date and getting   2016-09-23 13:07:46.091 RBook[1318:67957] Date = 2016-10-02 07:37:45 +0000

Comment: This is a very wrong way to make calendar calculations. You should use date components and date units.

Comment: @sailendrak. Thanks, actually the same object is updated from somewhere else , my method worked fine.